Why my exe disappear when it minimize after pyInstaller
When testing the code in the console it runs normally and all the functions work properly and after pyInstaller the problem comes. When I press the Minimize button, instead of appearing in the system tray, the icon disappears and in general the program is not in a window, but it works in the background? If anyone can help :)
I only tried with update pyInstaller and pystray, have no Idea what to do..
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


a = Analysis(
    ['web_search.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[('ImotSearch_MIcon.png', '.'), ('sent_ads.json', 'web')],
    hiddenimports=['requests', 'pystray'],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=True,
    optimize=0,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    [('v', None, 'OPTION')],
    name='web_search',
    debug=True,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
    icon=['ImotSearch_MIcon.png'],
)`

button:
def quit_window(icon, item):
    icon.stop()
    root.destroy()

def show_window(icon, item):
    icon.stop()
    root.after(0, root.deiconify)

def hide_window():
    root.withdraw()
    image = Image.open(r"ImotSearch_MIcon.png")
    menu = (item('Exit', quit_window), item('Open', show_window))
    icon = pystray.Icon("name", image, "web search", menu)
    icon.run()

minimize_button = tk.Button(root, text="Minimize", command=hide_window)
minimize_button.pack(pady=5)````


Most likely antivirus is deleting the executable. If it is the case then you may able to restore your AV's quarantine list.

The problem turned out to be entirely me. Here is a working version:
def hide_window(self):
    self.withdraw()
    self.tray_thread = Thread(target=self.create_tray_icon)
    self.tray_thread.daemon = True
    self.tray_thread.start()

def show_window(self):
    self.deiconify() 

